# xml in windows phone with linq

Tags: php, xml, vb.net, windows-phone-7, xaml

i am having this server side code :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Data>
<Entry> <?php echo time(); ?> </Entry>
</Data>
```

and this on a windows phone application :

```
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Private Sub cl_DownloadStringCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result)
        TextBox1.Text = doc.<Data>.<Entry>.Value
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cl As New WebClient
        AddHandler cl.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf cl_DownloadStringCompleted
        cl.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://localhost/wp/helloworld.php"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

but here is my problem : it does not change the values !
it show the same thing all the time !
it must be somthing like cached memory ... (?)

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add some fake data to your request:

```
cl.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://localhost/wp/helloworld.php?" + "fake="+DateTime.Now.Ticks));
```

This is a way to cheat the caching system of the OS.

And you don't need to pars the `fake` paramater on the serverside.

Comment: it works perfect ! thank you
but if i could empty the cached memory not to over do it , and crash the phone , it would be perfect !

Comment: My PHP is a little rusty, but server-side you could also do something like `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");`

Comment: actualy, this is a windows phone problem, not the server side.